# Method invocation "getMessage" may produce ’NullPointerExeption'

Tags: java

This is my code, Could someone please explain what the error means and if SaxParceExeption – Content is not allowed in prolog is related to this

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(name,password1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   if(task.isSuccessful()){
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "User Successfully Created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class));

                   }else {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "Error!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   }
```

Comment: check if `getException()` is returning null before invoking `getMessage()`

Comment: Do i have to write return! = null after else ?

Comment: your problem title says `task.getException().getMessage()` could produce NullPointerException, you can avoid it with this `Object exObj = task.getException();`  `((exObj) != null)?exObj.getMessage()):"No-Message";`

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that the method `task.getException()` can return null. Since you are calling `getMessage()` on top of this, it might cause a null pointer exception. So, you can check for null before invoking getMessage():

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(name,password1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   if(task.isSuccessful()){
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "User Successfully Created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class));

                   }else {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "Error!" + (task.getException() != null ? task.getException().getMessage(): ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   }
```